# How to remove the zero value?

Tags: c#, serial-port

[image]

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clos_flag) return;
        try
        {
            Listening = true;
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                this.txt_weight.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
               {

                   //txt_weight.Text = serialPort.ReadLine();
                   serialPort.NewLine = "\r";
                   string weight = serialPort.ReadLine();
                   if (weight.IndexOf(")") > 0)
                   {
                       weight = weight.Substring(3, 8);
                       // txt_weight.Text = weight.Substring(0, weight.LastIndexOf("0") + 1);
                   }
               }));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception eg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eg.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Listening = false;
        }
    }
```

What should i change to remove the first zero in the picture, above is the code i use. I tried to change the substring to (2,8) but still it is not working.
I get the value from a **weighing machine**, once the user click the "Open Serial Port" button

Comment: You typed ")" instead of "0" in your `if()` statement.

Comment: What does your `string weight = serialPort.ReadLine();` contains the exact string.??

Comment: Is there always a space(s) after that leading 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove leading Zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010702/how-to-remove-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
string weight = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

to this:

```
string weight = serialPort.ReadLine().TrimStart('0').Trim();
```

What that will do is readline, trim the first 0, then trim the outside (start amd end) blank spaces before loading the value into the declared variable

Comment: @David What does? when I run `Console.WriteLine("0 33200".TrimStart('0').Trim());` I get 33200

Comment: @David I see you selected an answer that has you hardcode weight. Did you never get my suggestion working? Also if you did make you can upvote this, even though you select an answer you can still upvote others who try to help you; either in useful comments or answers. Thanks

Comment: @David you can upvote as well to any answer you mark or comment you feel adds to your understanding of something.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this could be caused by many factors.

Looking at the code, the leading zero should be stripped out, since you already substring out the first two char.

I see that your function serialPort_DataReceived reads the data from a device in your port, so I presume your screen shot is from the output device.

Try and hard code

```
weight = "12345";
```

If the problem still persists, it would be caused not by the code, but by your device, etc..

Hope this helps~