# Remove leading zeros from string

Tags: c#, .net

I have File which has many lines related to bank account details. So while reading the file, sometimes the Account Number field is getting assigned with leading 0's as shown in this number `000123456782135435`. Could you please suggest me how can I avoid leading 0's ?

the Exact Number should be - `123456782135435` but Most of the time account number will be in 16 characters (For example like this : `6689161615476256`) but occasionally it will be leading with zero's like I showed.

Here leading zero's could be dynamic, that means it might be only 2 zero's or 3 zero's or 4 zero's etc..

My Sample File is:

> 120033324716940033324716940000000000PAPER KKK2015120329107000**1000000685226427**30000006348000000006055D   Closed Account      000000000000000000000000
> 120033334302970033334302970000000000PAPER MMM2015120106110240**0000000124001369**20000000130000000012987A   NSF-Insuf Funds     020151207000000000000000

So the issue is `0000000124001369` instead I must ready only `124001369`, but this happens very occasionally, most of the time starting from 62nd position we will have valid account number, please let me know how do I handle this situation

This is the exsisting code where I am reading the line position in a file for the accountNumber

```cs
 var accountNumber = Line.Substring(62, 16);
 NewFileLine =
    showToken => Line.Replace(Line.Substring(62, 16), showToken.PadRight(16))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove leading zeros using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010702/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [string.TrimStart()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-5.0) to remove leading `0`'s.

```cs
var accountNumber = "0000000124001369";
var trimmedNumber = accountNumber.TrimStart('0');
Console.WriteLine(accountNumber )    // 0000000124001369
Console.WriteLine(trimmedNumber )    // 124001369
```

Comment: You should close the question as duplicated instead answering